# Differentiating with respect to the exponent of distribution

Tags: derivatives, probability-distributions, optimization, distribution-theory

I want to see how the following expression increases or decreases with $n$.

$a-b(n)+\int Y(x)dF(x)^{n}$

Actually, $n$ is an integer, so that $F(x)^n$ actually means the distribution of

$max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$

But anyways, as a first step, I am assuming $n$ is a real number to take derivative. But I don't know how to take derivative with respect to $n$

Does it look like something like this

$-b'(n)+?$

But how should I differentiate that?

Comment: How can you differentiate with respect to an integer valued variable?

Comment: The answer very much depends on $b(n)$. So what is $b(n)$?

Comment: You can differentiate $\int nF^{n-1}YdF$ with respect to $n$.

Comment: @Jason So I wrote "But anyways, as a first step, I am assuming $n$ is a real number"

Comment: @zoli   $b$ is a function. Any function. But let's say $n^2$ if you want something concrete.

Comment: @J.G.  $F(x)^n$ is a distribution. $F(x)=P(X<x)$ whereas $F(x)^n=P(X_1<x, X_2<x, ..., X_n<x)$

Comment: If differentiation is completely impossible, what will be the difference equation?

Comment: If $F^n$ denotes the distribution of $\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$, then what does $F^t$ mean when $t$ is not an integer?